# Intermittent ASP.NET WebForms routing error

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms, iis-7.5, url-routing

I'm having a strange issue in my production website, which pops up somewhat consistently but with no known pattern.
My app consists of two websites, one of content which lists courses which the user can choose to apply, and the second under https where he actually applies (and pays) for it. I'm using routing in both of them (as per client's decision) and sometimes, when the user navigates from one to the other (a simple href link), upon 'arrival' on the https site, the routing with the course id gets lost and it redirects straight to the default.aspx page, and it crashes. I'm logging errors and I know for a fact that the loss of route (and routedata) is what's causing it (the route should be https://shop.courses.com/ins/{courseid}/ and it's throwing https://shop.courses.com/default.aspx).
In both cases I'm using WebForms, not MVC, and as mentioned, it's not constant. Both sites are hosted internally in a webfarm, running IIS 7.5

Comment: Can you post the route you are using?  At first glance the issue could be with the trailing slash.  I use routing a lot and a while back I wrote in a check and removal of trailing slashes.

Comment: The correct route should be shop.courses.com/ins/{courseid}/ where courseid is a long. If the end slash is the problem, I can remove it easily. The correct URL is on an intranet, I couldn't show you. THe global.asax ref is routes.MapPageRoute("", "ins/{courseid}/", "~/Default.aspx")

Comment: If its not a lot of work, you could try removing the trailing slash. Are you sure its not trying to find https://shop.courses.com/ins/[courseid]/default.aspx?  I'm reaching here (it's been a long time), but it might be looking for a default file in that directory and I *think* that may have been the reason I removed it in my code.

Comment: I can't seem to make it pop the error for me, I just get it because of my error log, but if that might be the case, I'm going to remove the slash and see how it goes.